# No response from URL in XML parsing - Alamofire Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xml, alamofire, xmlmapper

I am using [XMLMapper](https://github.com/gcharita/XMLMapper) with [AlamoFire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) request to get response. URL is working fine on browsers but when I try to use in swift it skips the function. Even I cannot debug the response. Its before parsing, not getting any data or response from the URL. Any idea ??

```
func xmlParser() {
        let urlXml = "https://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss"

        Alamofire.request(urlXml, method: .get).responseXMLObject { (response: DataResponse<RSSFeed>) in
            let rssFeed = response.result.value
            print(rssFeed?.channel?.items?.first?.title ?? "nil")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that something is wrong with your model. I managed to map the response from this link.

Try using the following structure and compare it with yours to see the difference:

```
class RSSFeed: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var channel: Channel?

    required init?(map: XMLMap) {}

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        channel <- map["channel"]
    }
}

class Channel: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var title: String?
    var link: URL?
    var description: String?
    var language: String?
    var copyright: String?
    var pubDate: String?
    var lastBuildDate: String?
    var category: String?
    var generator: String?
    var docs: URL?
    var items: [Item]?

    required init?(map: XMLMap) {}

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        title <- map["title"]
        link <- (map["link"], XMLURLTransform())
        description <- map["description"]
        language <- map["language"]
        copyright <- map["copyright"]
        pubDate <- map["pubDate"]
        lastBuildDate <- map["lastBuildDate"]
        category <- map["category"]
        generator <- map["generator"]
        docs <- (map["docs"], XMLURLTransform())
        items <- map["item"]
    }
}

class Item: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var title: String?
    var link: URL?
    var description: String?
    var pubDate: String?

    required init?(map: XMLMap) {}

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        title <- map["title"]
        link <- (map["link"], XMLURLTransform())
        description <- map["description"]
        pubDate <- map["pubDate"]
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.